# WCF Web Service client unit test failed in Visual Studio 2012 when hosting on local IIS

Tags: unit-testing, wcf-client, visual-studio-2012

So I tried to start writing Windows 8 Modern Style application in visual Studio 2012 using Test Driven approach.  I basically treat my Win8 WinRT as a client for tons of WCF Web service hosting on IIS.  So as for now, all of my unit tests are WCF Web service call.

All unit tests pass if the WCF web services are hosted in IIS on ANOTHER MACHINE.  However, all of them failed if I host the same set of web services on local IIS.  I already checked the manifest and made sure that the following items are checked:

[x] Enterprise Authentication

[x] Internet (Client

[x] Internet (Client and Server)

[x] Private Networks (Client and Server)

BTW:

- I wrote those tests in MSTest because it has native support to async and await, which is necessary for testing async web service call.
- I went ahead and start working on a simple Windows 8 Modern Style app and make Web Service (hosting in local IIS) call in the app, and I got NO ERROR.

So I am very puzzled.  Does it have something to do with the Visual Studio 2012 Test Engine?  Is there something I can do to fix the problem.  I really want to continue doing the app in Test Driven style but I can't find another way to test my async unit tests.

Any suggestion?